# Can't test the PHP package using PHPUnit, once I publish it

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, autoload

I've created a simple PHP library using PHP 5.6.
It includes PHPUnit test cases and I succeeded in creating the package.
Then I found that I can install these packages directly from GitHub, using composer, in other projects also. I can run tests independently at the development stage. But once I publish the package I can't run the tests, as it is not properly finding the autoloader files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader">

<testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I've added the xml files in root directory. The path of the autoload file is correct when it is independent. But the directory structure will be a different one once it is installed.

The problem still persist if we use `require_once` the autoloader file, as the directory structure change after installation.

Questions:

1. Can we test our package after installing it into any frameworks (laravel/Symfony) or in any other projects?
2. What is the best practice? Is the test needed for the developers who is using the package?
3. If yes, then any solution to solve this? Is there any other method to autoload problem in both environments?

[Repo in Github](https://github.com/jerintk/Validator)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you're best to look at the other repositories and see if it works or not.

For me

`cd vendor/phpunit/phpunit && composer install && phpunit` => worked
`cd doctrine/collections/ && composer install && phpunit` => worked

So it seems that it should be working for you.

If you look at the `phpunit.xml.dist` for the other vendors they use:

`bootstrap="./tests/Doctrine/Tests/TestInit.php"` (doctrine)
`bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"` (phpunit)

It looks like your file isn't so different. Are you sure you ran `composer install` from inside your packages directory inside the vendor folder?

#### Update:

I added your repository as a dependency to a default Symfony installation.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "url": "https://github.com/jerintk/Validator.git",
        "type": "git"
    }
],
```

And in the `require` block:

`"Jthedev/Validators": "dev-master"`

I then ran

`composer update`

It ran fine. You need to run composer update and check in the new composer.lock because it's out of date.

From there I cd'ed into the directory for your repo.

`cd vendor/Jthedev/Validators`

I then ran

`composer install`

and

`vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

and got

`OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)`

#### Update Two

(since this was too long for a comment)

@JTheDev `composer update` adds your dependencies for the laravel project, but it doesn't create the vendor folder inside your `vendor/your-project` directory. If composer installed all dependencies separately for each project, like:

```
vendor/
  my-project/
    vendor/
      dependency-A
      dependency-C
  another-library/
    vendor/
      dependency-A
      dependency-B
```

it would waste a lot of space and bandwidth. Instead composer gets all the dependencies and installs them in separate folders and they work with each other because composer loads them all using `vendor/autoload.php` *for that project*. What you're talking about is creating the vendor folder inside `vendor/your-project`. This is not normal - usually you only have to run tests when developing yourself, but anyway your question is about how to run your tests for your project when it's added as a dependency for another project.

To do this you *need* to run composer install *inside* the `vendor/your-project` directory, that means:

`cd vendor/Jthedev/Validators && composer install && vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

#### Final update (hopefully)

From chat:

The autoloader is only generated when you run composer install inside your project directory. You are correct, the vendor folder should not be there usually but you need it if you want to do what you are trying to do. It is not conventional. Normally developers run their tests inside their project root folder, not on the dependencies, but your questions was "how can I run my tests when it is a dependency". The answer is you need to create the vendor and autoload files inside your project folder

The tests only run if you run composer install inside the project folder. But it's not a problem if the tests don't run without doing that.

Comment: I think my question need an edit or it's not clear. I don't have any problem with the package when it is independent. The vendor folder is in the root folder, so is the phpunit.xml. but when we install that package into a framework, XML file will be residing deep inside the vendor folder. In that case, the package can't track the autoloader. That's my problem. If you clone my GitHub repo, it won't result in any issues. But when you install it with in another package, you can't test it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You mean the `cd vendor/yournamespace/yourpackage && composer install && phpunit` doesn't work when it's added as a dependency? Or are you expecting your packages tests to be run automatically from the root folder with just `phpunit`?

Comment: No no. Sorry for the wrong meaning. Let's say you're developing a package for packagist. And if some one installing it in their project. In that case. Keep in mind that the package is framework independent. Like carbon, Mailgun, etc... Regardless of framework, the package should work. It is working but not the tests. Hope it's clear. You can try installing my GitHub repo and run the tests.

Comment: @JTheDev, are you expecting your _library's_ tests to run if somebody runs `phpunit` from the root of a project that simply requires your library via Composer?

Comment: Not that much. I'm expecting the test should succeed atleast when they run the tests inside the vendor folder and inside my package.

Comment: I added it as a dependency and the tests run fine. I'm not sure what error you're having.

Comment: @mickadoo: Could you please share me the steps you've undertaken to do the test? What I've done is, I installed laravel first. Added my package as one of the dependency. Then I did the composer update. After that, I did the `phpunit` inside the `vendor/namespace/package/tests`. Unfortunately, it couldn't find the autoload file.

Comment: @JTheDev I added some clarification for how you can run the tests.

Comment: @mickadoo: how about my procedure, is that correct or did I made any mistake? I've added one screenshot too...

Comment: Please read the update. It has all the steps you need to run the tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136337/discussion-between-jthedev-and-mickadoo).